# How can I get deface to compile in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I am building a Spree site and theming it with Deface.  I was using Spree 1.0.3 with Rails 3.1.4.  I had no problems with Deface in development as the overrides compiled successfully on browser refreshes.  I have since upgraded to Spree 1.1.0 with Rails 3.2.3.  Now the overrides don't compile on browser refreshes, so I have to restart the development server for each change to take effect.  Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 0):

Tyler: this is a known issue in the newest versions. You can follow the issue here https://github.com/railsdog/deface/issues/37 until it's fixed.